# How to make calls to Fine-Grained Access Control DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I'm working with [Fine-Grained Access Control for DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.html) and while I have a fairly good idea on how to restrict access to table rows by userid now, I don't know what the actual API calls need to look like. Will the userid be inserted automatically? How would I retrieve and store items then? Do I have to find my own userid and always use that as the hash for all my calls? Is it enforced somewhere that I use my actual userid? Does anyone have any examples that make use of this?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.Examples.html

Comment: @Mircea Yes, those are examples for the policies, but I mean an example for actual code that writes to or reads from the table